# How to post current date and time as text?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to post this text:

> At (Current hour and minute) CET, On (Current Week-Day) (Current Date) of (Current Month), (Current Year).

So it looks something like:

> At 10:00 CET on Thursday 26th of November, 2020 and some text after that.

Is it possible to make a macro like that for a button?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub doShowCurrentDateAndTime()
  Dim t As Date: t = Now()
  Dim current_time As String: current_time = Format(t, "hh:mm")
  Dim current_day As String: current_day = Format(t, "dddd")
  Dim current_date As String: current_date = getOrdinalDate(t)
  Dim current_month As String: current_month = Format(t, "mmmm")
  Dim current_year As String: current_year = Format(t, "yyyy")
  
  Dim s As String: s = "At " & current_time & " CET on " & _
    current_day & " " & current_date & " of " & current_month & _
    ", " & current_year
  
  ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value = s
End Sub
```

```
Public Function getOrdinalDate(ByVal dte_toformat As Date) As String
  '// based on :https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6742
  Dim day_suffix As String: day_suffix = vbNullString
  Select Case Day(dte_toformat)
    Case 1, 21, 31
      day_suffix$ = Day(dte_toformat) & "st"
    Case 2, 22
      day_suffix$ = Day(dte_toformat) & "nd"
    Case 3, 23
      day_suffix$ = Day(dte_toformat) & "rd"
    Case Else
      day_suffix$ = Day(dte_toformat) & "th"
  End Select
  getOrdinalDate = day_suffix
End Function
```

To link a macro to a button on the worksheet:

- RightClick on the button
- Select 'Assign Macro'
- Highlight the macro you want to use
- Select 'OK'

Comment: Amazing work. I have never used anything like this before. I tried to copy it into a Module. The thing is, i have made a button i want all that text to be pasted into a cell (D3 to be exact) How would i make this paste into just one cell. If it is even possible.. Once again thank you so much!

Comment: No problem - I wasn't sure where you wanted to show the output.  I'll update my answer,  Please accept it as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Amazing that actually worked. Do you know how to change the weekday to English, since it´s currently making it Danish.

Comment: The format is picked up by your Windows System Settings.  Might be worth checking / changing those.